# URL preview doesn't match what's rendered

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, unicode

In [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/n%c4%ablaka%e1%b9%87%e1%b9%adha-dh%c4%81ra%e1%b9%87%c4%ab-great-compassion-mantra-correct-translation-in-english), this url -- `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%ABlaka%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%ADha_Dh%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87%C4%AB` -- looks like this in the preview ...

> [image]

... and like this in the posted question ...

> [image]